# Windows 8 - Cannot run taskmanager

Tags: windows, windows-8

I'm unable to launch Task Manager in my Windows 8(x64 bit) installation. It says "This app can't run on your PC". Probably my PC is infected, however none of the AntiVirus softwares are able to detect. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Run regedit.exe, go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\taskmgr.exe` and delete the string `Debugger`.

Now you should be able to run Taskmgr again.

Comment: Hi, taskmgr.exe entry is not present...

Comment: run this DISM command to repair corrupted Windows files: http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx